# Performance monitoring an AWS IOT core serverless architecture

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, serverless-framework, aws-iot, aws-xray

I am working on an AWS serverless architecture that can be roughly described as follows:

1 Things reporting to [IOT Core](https://aws.amazon.com/iot-core/)

2 From IOT Core the messages arrive to [Kinesis](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/)

3 Kinesis to different [Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) functions

4 Lambda send messages (or not) to be stored on [dynamodb](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/)

This is obviously a VERY high level description but I hope it might be enough to explain my question.

What I would like to do is understand how long my messages are spending on each station along the way. So for example, Message X took a total of 1 second to process and complete its life cycle and the time spent is divided as follows: 100ms on IOT Core, 100ms on Kinesis, 400ms on a specific lambda function and another 400ms to store on dynamodb.

To do the above, [AWS XRAY](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/index.html) seems to be the natural option but according to its [supported services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-usage.html#xray-usage-services), IOT Core and Kinesis are not included. Is there any other way to do the request above? Am I missing something with XRAY?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, since AWS X-Ray does not support tracing with kinesis per message level tracing would be hard. However you may write custom code using X-Ray SDK to propagate context information manually. I would recommend to check out X-Ray SDK (language of your choice). Here's some reference on that ([How can use the Java Kinesis Client Library together with X-Ray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49280253/how-can-use-the-java-kinesis-client-library-together-with-x-ray))